# Esoterica or esoterics?

Tags: grammatical-number

As plural nouns, I'm struggling to see the distinction. [Wiktionary gives](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esoterica#English):

> esoterica (plural only)
>
> Things that are esoteric; things that are impractical or specialised.

And claims that [esoterics is a plural of esoteric](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esoteric#Noun):

> esoteric (plural esoterics)
>
> An esoteric doctrine or treatise; esoteric philosophy.

That would settle the argument, but is also says that esoterics is a [different word altogether](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esoterics#English):

> esoterics (uncountable)
>
> The study of esoterica

So what would I use if I wanted to say something like, "*I would be good at the English language, but I've yet to master its **[blank]***"?

Comment: Esoterica is more esoteric.

Comment: 'Esoterica' equates to 'idiosyncrasies' and would fit (but as Hot Licks implies is highfalutin': try 'oddities' etc); 'esoterics' is 'esoteric doctrines etc' or the study of these, and doesn't fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **esoterics** does not appear in Lexico (Oxford) online dictionary.

[**Esoteric**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/esoteric) is an adjective so it does not become a plural.

[**Esoterica**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/esoterica) is a mass noun, and doesn't really describe the oddities of language.

Your choice does not really fit, so I suggest your *blank* could be

> I have yet to master its [**peculiarities**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/peculiarity).

Or more simply,

> I have yet to master its **finer points**.